# Wordpress category title not update in navigation menu

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, menus

I have simple situation but can't get the right answer and solution

**Problem:**
for example my woocommerce category name 
**“soup, noodle & pasta”** 
I add this category in my menu and after that will change my category name
“pizza, pasta & noddles” 
it should  automatically update in in menu too.

but unfortunately it's not working.

**Think I already did**
I tried to disabled all plugin not happened
I tried to change theme same result

**test case**
If you have category simple category name e.g "contact" it will work fine.

My issue is when I put special character like "," or "&" i face this issue

Comment: Please contact the plugin author directly - this is related to their specific plugin code, not anything we here could help with.

Comment: @WebElaine well I am not using any plugin it's default behavior of WordPress

I install fresh WordPress and use WordPress default theme still facing the same issue

Comment: In the inital post you said "I have this test case in other menu plugin and it’s not updated that’s why I confirming before buy this plugin." Your post still says "for my woocommerce category name." Are you saying you have tried creating a Core Post, Page, or Category with that same type of name including an amperand, put it in a Core Menu in a default theme, and you're still encountering issues?

Comment: @webelaine yes first i think it's issue with plugin but then I tried on fresh WordPress installation and use WordPress default theme still get the same error

so yes still getting error with default theme and fresh installation. I also report to WordPress team.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred in WordPress core development.

they give me answer on below ticket thread

Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2019 15:36:49 -0400
Subject: [PATCH 1/2] Added special character decode to menu item title

---

src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php b/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php
index f130d2f3e1..db8a2fcf78 100644

find this code on above directory

```
if ( $args['menu-item-title'] == $original_title ) {
```

and replace with

```
if ( wp_unslash( $args['menu-item-title'] ) == wp_specialchars_decode( $original_title ) ) {
```

[Wordpress Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48011)